# Can unit vectors $i, j, $ and $k$ be elements of a group?

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory

A collection of some vectors under  group operations may form an abelian group. By the cancellation law of groups, the unit vectors $i, j, $ and $k$ along x-axis, y-axis and z- axis, respectively cannot be the elements of a group, because $i.j=i.k$ but $j\neq k$ implies that cancellation law fails for these vectors . Is these my intuitions correct? Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It depends greatly on the operation.

Comment: If your $i.j$ is the dot product of $i$ and $j$ then you're already not talking about a group since that "product" is a real number, not a group element. Your observation that you don't have cancellation is still (of course) correct, and important to know.

Comment: Well sir, do you mean that dot product cannot be a group operation?

Comment: @gete This might be trivial, but maybe you have overlookd it: if you use the + operation, then your vector space is already a group

Comment: @gete dot product cannot be a group operation because it does not give you a vector. A group operation is a map $G \times G \to G$ (such that...).

Comment: Means if we suppose our group to be a collection of vectors and group operation as dot product then after aplying the dot products  we will no more be in the supposed group , i.e., closure property fails here?

Comment: @gete: If $X$ is a set, a *(binary) operation on $X$* is a function $X\times X\to X$. A group is often described as a set $G$ together with a binary operation $\cdot$ on $G$ satisfying certain properties (it can be defined other ways, with three different operations, but never mind). In particular, the dot product of $3$-dimensional vectors cannot be made into a group operation, because the inputs are $3$-dimensional vectors, but the outputs are real numbers. (You could do all sorts of really weird things to fix this problem, but they would all be very artificial).

Comment: @Daniel: oops, you're right. Better retract my suggestion. Might be a semigroup, but clearly not a group.

Answer (score 2):

The unit vectors $i,j,k$ can all be elements of the same abelian group. One specific example is if you take your set to be all vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and use the operation of vector addition.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you look up 'quaternion group'.

Comment: This isn't awfully helpful - at least give the operation!